# No Eclipse console output window (Java)?

Tags: java, eclipse

![http://oi49.tinypic.com/eu0yth.jpg][1]

The image shows what the console output gives me. I checked the error file and there are no errors?

This was working like 5 hours ago? It gives me the exact same console output on different types of programs when I run them.

Comment: Not sure what your question is, you are not able to see console window?

Comment: @RohitJain I'm guessing he's trying to show how Eclipse is showing it. As you can see it's Red text, which has to mean something different.

Comment: @Austin. Ok. Didn't understand the question. And by the time you posted your comment I deleted mine. :(

Comment: Are you Sure you are running the right file. Could there be another class in the other project in your workspace, maybe called `AquaLauoutStyle`?

Comment: Nambari, yes, I can't see the console window. Like the output. It gives mm "gap= 4 gap= 0" for every program I run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the stderr output of the execution of the main method of AquaLayoutStyle

Comment: Ok, so how do I get it to show me the console output?

Comment: Right click you code you have shown -> Run As -> Java Application

Answer (score 2):

This might be the reason for actual problem.

You should not use `==` for equality check in case of stings. Use `.equals()` to do equality check for any kind of objects in Java.

Comment: It was working fine before when I ran the program, and as I said I get the same output for every program I run. So I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: It may not be the problem but is definitely not correct.

Comment: @user1792312: Do you mean that you get the same output not matter what file you run?

Comment: I will use change it to .equals() however, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

You are not running the right program. The source code displayed is having the class name as `DoesMyFinchWork` while the error screen(console output title bar) says , you ran `AquaLayoutStyle` class.

Please right click `DoesMyFinchWork` source file and select `Run As -> Java Application` to run your  `DoesMyFinchWork`.

Comment: Sorry but Martin Serrano answered the question correct before you. I gave him tick for correct answer, but thank you for help me!

Comment: @user1792312 This is fine. I saw that answer and it looked partial. Typing full with more sentences to form, took little longer.